# executing javascript function on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Right now, I have a javascript function which is triggered onclick. However, I want the same function to be triggered when DOM is loaded. Following code works, however, I don't want to put 'script' tag in the middle of the view. Calling the function from the body tag is not an option here.

```
<script>document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",function(){extractions.RefreshCheck(@check.ID)});</script>
```

Code snippet of where I want to implement this:

```
@foreach (var check in Model.FailedChecks)
{
   <li class="@( check.IsOK ? Html.Raw("bg-success") : Html.Raw("bg-danger") ) " cid="@check.ID">
    @Html.ActionLink(check.Display, "XList", "XList", new { filter = check.GetQuery(), Layout = check.Layout }, new { target = "_blank" }); 
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh" onclick="extractions.RefreshCheck(@check.ID);" onload="initAutoRefresh"></span>

    @*<script>document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",function(){extractions.RefreshCheck(@check.ID)});</script>*@
  </li>
}
```

Above codes work, but I do not want that script tag in my view. So I tried to add the following code in my javascript file using 'onload' eventlistner and  it does not work. I think this is the problem.

```
@foreach (var check in Model.FailedChecks)
{
   <li class="@( check.IsOK ? Html.Raw("bg-success") : Html.Raw("bg-danger") ) " cid="@check.ID">
    @Html.ActionLink(check.Display, "XList", "XList", new { filter = check.GetQuery(), Layout = check.Layout }, new { target = "_blank" }); 
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh" onclick="extractions.RefreshCheck(@check.ID);" onload="extractions.InitAutoRefresh()"></span>

  </li>
}
```

And my InitAutoRefresh function :

```
var extractions= {
    InitAutoRefresh: function () {
    if (document.readyState === 'complete') {
        RefreshCheck();
        console.log("function already loaded in DOM")
    } else {
        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
            RefreshCheck();
            console.log("function loaded in dom");
        });
    }

  },
RefreshCheck: function(intCheckId){
    $('li[cid=' + intCheckId + ']').addClass('bold');
    $.get(window.location + '/Home/UpdateIntegritycheck?checkId=' + intCheckId, function(data){
        $('li[cid='+intCheckId+']').replaceWith(data);
    });
  }
}
```

Function RefreshCheck works fine on click (i.e. it updates record). I would be more than happy to get your feedbacks. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach is to define custom attribute on your html tags on which you can fire conditionaly according to the tag value. Example :

```
 <span data-click-on-dom-ready="true" onclick="extractions.RefreshCheck(@check.ID);" ></span>
```

Then far away from your partial view, you can put the following:

```
$(document).ready(function () { 
  $("[data-click-on-dom-ready='true']").trigger('click');
});
```

Comment: thanks, looks very promising. will definitely give a shot.

Comment: thanks for the answer. Learned a new trick today. If you think my question is worth, please give me a up vote.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
@section scripts{
    <script>document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () { xtractions.RefreshCheck(id) });</script>
}
```

Comment: This works and I have tried it. But my constraint is, I do not want to use javascript code in my view. Right now, I am using this and it works but I do not want js code inside my view (btw, it's a partial view). `<script>document.readyState === 'complete' ? extractions.RefreshCheck(@check.ID) : document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () { extractions.RefreshCheck(@check.ID) });</script>`

Answer (score 0):

if you are using jquery then you can use

```
$(document).ready(function () { 
  your code here
});
```

Comment: can you please describe how do you call this function from span tag? I tried it but could not find a possible way to call this js function from my span tag. Thanks for showing interest.

Comment: Following code did not work. `$(document).ready(function () {
 var result;
 if (document.readyState === 'complete') {
  result=extractions.RefreshCheck(intCheckId);
  console.log("function already loaded in DOM")
 } else {
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
   result=extractions.RefreshCheck(intCheckId);
   console.log("function loaded in dom");
  });
 }
 $('.glyphicon-refresh').html(result);
});`

Comment: no no call your function in $(document).ready(function () { your code });